Django unit test fixing database row id
from django.test import TestCase

class DefTests(TestCase):

    def setUp(self): 
       # first made the label
       UserType(label="mylabel").save() ## UserType is model object, and I made the first row , the id is supposed to be 1

    def test_my(self):
       u = UserType.objects.get(id=1) # UserType.DoesNotExis error

I guess in test mode real insert is not executed, so id is not fixed.
Am I correct?
Then, Is there any way to fix the id in advance before doing test_****?

Typically you attach the object, or its id to the test instance, so:
from django.test import TestCase


class DefTests(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # first made the label
        user_type = UserType.objects.create(label='mylabel')
        self.user_type_id = user_type.pk

    def test_my(self):
        u = UserType.objects.get(id=self.user_type_id)
another option is to enforce the primary key, a potential problem is however that tests can run in any order, so it is, strictly speaking, possible that there is already a UserType with that id, and not per se the one we thus want to save:
from django.test import TestCase


class DefTests(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # first made the label
        user_type = UserType.objects.create(pk=1, label='mylabel')

    def test_my(self):
        u = UserType.objects.get(pk=1)
That being said, forcing primary keys looks like a bad idea: typically a primary key should be treated as a "blackbox value": the fact that it is an int is more an implementation detail, since for instance adding up two primary keys does not make much sense.


Note: It is usually better to use .create(…) [Django-doc] to create a record in the database, than to instantiate a model object and .save(…) [Django-doc] it: when you save a model instance, it first looks if there is already a record, so this can increase the number of queries on the database.

